# Call generic method

Tags: java, generics

Why I cannot use parametrized method like method1(Foo1)? I want to pass only classes that extend class Foo.

```
public class Foo1 extends Foo {
}


public class Foo2 {

   void method1(Class<Foo>){
   }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Make your method a generic method that accepts a parameterized type:

```
<T extends Foo> void method1(Class<T> arg) {
    ...
}
```

or, more tersely:

```
void method1(Class<? extends Foo> arg) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `T` is unnecessary. `void method1(Class<? extends Foo> arg)` is equivalent

Comment: @newacct - Indeed it is equivalent (except perhaps for compiler error messages if one tries to call `method1` with an incompatible type). As a matter of style I tend to favor named generic parameters, but here it doesn't make much difference.